# What's the difference between [label setAlpha:] and label.alpha?

Tags: objective-c

What is the difference between these two lines of code? They both work and both do the same, but is there any reason why one is preferable to the other, and if so why?

```
[textLabel setAlpha:0];
textLabel.alpha=0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Old style and new style, both do the same. No difference and no preference.

Answer (score 1):

Using the "`.alpha`" property calls the setter, which is "`setAlpha:`", so ultimately you're calling the exact same code.

It's just a style difference and/or a preference for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. The compiler translates

```
textLabel.alpha = 0;
```

into

```
[textLabel setAlpha:0];
```

However, some people prefer to use the "dot notation" only with *properties*,
even if  the language does not impose this restriction.